# How to create a linux pipeline example in c

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am trying to learn how to use the pipe() command in C, and trying to create a test program to duplicate the functionality of `ls | grep ".c"`, if I were to enter this into a linux terminal. If I enter this into the terminal, I only get `test.c` as a result.

My code is as follows:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "fcntl.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 int pipefd[2];
 int childpid,childpid2;
 char* cmd[3]={"ls",NULL,NULL};
 char* cmd2[3]={"grep",".c",NULL};
 pipe(pipefd);
 if(childpid=fork()){
   //parent
 }else{  
   //child
   //write
   close(pipefd[0]);
   dup2(pipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
   execvp("ls", cmd);
 }
 if(childpid2=fork()){
 }
 else{
   close(pipefd[1]);
   dup2(pipefd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
   execvp("grep",cmd2);
 }
 close(pipefd[0]);
 close(pipefd[1]);
 return 0;
}
```

This code returns me the following results ($ is the terminal prompt):

```
$a.out
$test.c
(blank line)
```

The program doesn't complete, but hangs until I quit it. What problems do I have? How can I mimic the terminal? I'm new to C, and using a premade template of a program, so forgive me if there are glaring mistakes.

Comment: Apart from `test.c` what other files exist in your directory - were you expecting multiple lines of output?

Comment: I was only expecting test.c. I was just trying to find the C files in the directory, but it wasn't giving me another terminal prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 int pipefd[2];
 int childpid,childpid2;
 char* cmd[3]={"ls",NULL,NULL};
 char* cmd2[3]={"grep",".c",NULL};
 pipe(pipefd);
 if(childpid=fork()){
   //parent
   close(pipefd[1]);
   dup2(pipefd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
   execvp("grep",cmd2);
 }else{  
   //child
   //write
   close(pipefd[0]);
   dup2(pipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
   execvp("ls", cmd);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the program exits right away — in fact, the parent process exits *before* the children run, which is why there's a shell prompt before "test.c".

You can improve things a bit by adding this in your parent:

```
wait(childpid);
wait(childpid2);
```

which will make the parent exit after both children.

Answer (score 1):

Your program quits immediately, while your processes run in the background. They overwrite the prompt, and makes you think the program is still running even though the shell is waiting for your input (press enter or type a command blindly and see.

You only see `test.c` because that's the only matching file in your directory (also note that you're checking for "filenames containing c anywhere except the first character", not "ending in .c" which would be `grep '\.c$'`).

The simple fix is to add:

```
wait(NULL); wait(NULL);
```

right before your `return 0`.

Comment: Files ending in `.c` would need `grep "\.c$"` if you want to be picky since the dot by itself is "any character". More usual would be `ls *.c` - but that wouldn't demonstrate the use of a pipe...

Comment: The markup ate the `\ `. You can't do `ls *.c` here though, since globs are a shell feature.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but here's an older answer that was never provided. Use [libpipeline](http://libpipeline.nongnu.org/). libpipeline is a pipeline manipulation library. The use case is one of the `man` page maintainers who had to frequently use a command like the following (and work around associated OS bugs):

```
zsoelim < input-file | tbl | nroff -mandoc -Tutf8
```

Here's the libpipeline way:

```
pipeline *p;
int status;

p = pipeline_new ();
pipeline_want_infile (p, "input-file");
pipeline_command_args (p, "zsoelim", NULL);
pipeline_command_args (p, "tbl", NULL);
pipeline_command_args (p, "nroff", "-mandoc", "-Tutf8", NULL);
status = pipeline_run (p);
```

The [libpipeline](http://libpipeline.nongnu.org/) has more examples on its homepage. The library is also included in many distros, including Arch, Debian, Fedora, [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/8.4/chapter03/packages.html) and Ubuntu.